# Unable to importxml from this URL

Tags: google-sheets, xml, xpath, importxml

I am trying to fetch url using `=importxml` in Google Sheets, but getting error message, could not connect to url.

He is the formula which I am using:

`=IMPORTXML("https://api.exotel.com/v1/Accounts/adani1/Calls/204f65298ee96c915f57fc4c1df94a46","//*[@id='collapsible1']/div[1]/div[2]/div[9]/span[2]")`

Ultimately I want to fetch "Status" from this URL.

Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

IMPORTXML only is able to access public web resources but he URL in the formula requires user and password so it couldn't be reached.

Comment: Yes you're right! That page lead to a `username` and `password` and it's officialy recognized by Google that `importxml` doesn't support login pages.